# Fetch PUT : SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I'm sending files (image / video) on amazon S3 with Fetch but I don't understand why I can't reach the response.

The image / video is properly update on amazon and I can access it on my bucket.

```
 const result = await fetch(url.data, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: path,
    });
    const json = await result.json();
    console.log(json);

// url.data : presigned url
// path : {uri : https....com}
```

And i got the following error : `Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF`

any idea ?

Comment: What comes back isn't JSON? Have you looked at `result`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing returned in result

Comment: Just put your code in try catch statement and see what error occurred . Just better way to debug !... Moreover the fetch request isn't returning a valid json !

Comment: If there's nothing in the result it's not parseable as JSON because there's nothing to parse.

Comment: Yes sure but why there is no response from the server ?

Comment: No error is catch by the Try / Catch so it's not very helpfull

Comment: Because it doesn't send one? Wouldn't it make sense to include all the relevant information, like the S3 endpoint you're using, a link to the docs, or something someone could use to help? I mean if you're getting a valid, non-error response back, I'm not sure what the issue is. Do you think you're *supposed* to get something back?